# Why TweenAnimationBuilder is not able to infer the type using its tween property?

Tags: dart

```dart
TweenAnimationBuilder(
  tween: Tween<int>(begin: 0, end: 1),
  builder: (_, value, __) {
    return Container();
  },
)
```

I'm providing a `Tween<int>` to `tween`, and according to my understanding, the `value` parameter in the `builder` should be of type `int` (at runtime it is definitely of type `int` but not at the compile time). Why is that so?

On the contrary, in the following code:

```dart
List<T> _getNewList<T>(List<T> list) => List<T>.from(list);
```

This code can infer its type from the arguments supplied.

```dart
final foo = _getNewList(<int>[1, 2]); // foo is of type `List<int>`
```

Answer (score 2):

The way Dart type inference works is that a missing type argument, like the `<T>` type parameter on `TweenAnimationBuilder` is first checked against the calling context. If that doesn't give a type, then the arguments are analyzed *individually* without any hint to the type variable's type, and then the type argument is inferred as something allowing the argument's types.

In this case, `tween` is analyzed to have type `Tween<int>` and `builder` is analyzed to have type `Widget Function(BuildContext, dynamic, Widget)` *because there is no clue to the second argument's type from the context*.
The type analysis does not use information derived from one argument to infer `T` before finding the type of the second argument (that could be wrong if case the second one *requires* a looser type).

Then the type inference tries to find a type argument to `TweenAnimationBuilder` satisfying both of these, which ends up with `<dynamic>` because of the `builder` type.

If you only have one argument, or only one argument depending on the type argument, or you have multiple arguments that *agree* on the type, then things work out.

If you have multiple parameters depending on the type variable, no context type which locks the type variable down, and only one of the arguments actually constrain the type argument, then ... well, this happens, the other argument is unconstrained and that makes the inferred type argument be `dynamic`. Either write `TweenAnimationBuilder<int>(...)` or `..., builder: (_, int value, _) => ...` so that you have a type hint on all paths.

Comment: Thank you sir as always for your nice explanation. But sir, if I take an example of `Iterable.fold` method. If I use, `<int>[1].fold(0.0,(a, b)=>a+b);`, the inferred type should be `double`, because all the arguments are given explicit type `double`. But again it infers to dynamic. Should I ask this as a separate question if it requires more lines for you to answer?